# MongoDB Aggregation - Find customers in zip code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

I have 2 MongoDB documents: shop and customer

shop documents are like below

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    zipcodes:[ 
      '12345',
      '11111',
    ]
  },  
  {
    id:2,
    zipcodes:[
      '45678',
    ]
  }
]
```

customer documents are like below

```
[
  {
    id:20,
    name: 'First Last',
    address: [
      {
        id:110,
        address: 'address line1',
        zipcode: '12345',
      },
      {
        id:111,
        address: 'address new',
        zipcode: '45678',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id:25,
    name: 'First Last2',
    address: [
      {
        id:113,
        address: 'address new',
        zipcode: '45678',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id:29,
    name: 'First Name',
    address: [
      {
        id:119,
        address: 'address liner',
        zipcode: '11111',
      },
      {
        id:120,
        address: 'address new2',
        zipcode: '12345',
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Expected output:
I need to get customers in the same zip code

```
[
  {
    zipcode: 12345,
    customers:[
      {id:20},
      {id:29},
    ]
  },
  {
    zipcode: 11111,
    customers:[
      {id:29},
    ]
  },
  {
    zipcode: 45678,
    customers:[
      {id:25},
    ]
  },
]
```

I tried to solve this using MongoDB aggregation framework but no luck so far.
I have no idea how to match object elements in an array.
Thanks in advance. Please help.

Comment: Would be great to share the expected output document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `zipcodes` array to multiple documents.
2. `$lookup` - Join `shops` with `customers` collection.

   2.1. `$match`  - `shops`' `zipcode` is within `address.zipcode` from `customers`.

   2.2. `$project` - Decorate the output documents for `customers` array.
3. `$project` - Decorate the output documents.

```
db.shops.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$zipcodes"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "customers",
      let: {
        zipcodes: "$zipcodes"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              "$in": [
                "$$zipcodes",
                "$address.zipcode"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            id: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "customers"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      zipcodes: 1,
      customers: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vJQyxdBd-m6)

Comment: thanks. it works in the pabove playgroud but It throws an error when running in actual database. "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: string"

Comment: Hi, I suspect that there is a document with `address` not an array. For this scenario, you may refer to this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RukqwWo9IyQ).